# Visual Studio XML Documentation...library?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xml-documentation

Is there a software/app that could stored all our VS2008 XML documentation comments files in one place and could act as a library for all this doc ?

We are creating many web projects that are all interconnected, and we need to put in 1 place all the XML docs created by VS. So it could act as a place where we could access all the doc and search code or reference through a single software/app.

Sure its XML and we could create our XSLT and transform all the docs, but we are looking first for something already done. Custom app is our second choice.

Thanks for your recommendations !

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/GhostDoc/)?

There are lots of other projects that do similar things - [SandCastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) and [nDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use a utility like NDoc or Sandcastle to create your docs from your Xml comments and then hold these all in a common area.

Both of these are Freeware and I know NDoc can produce help files in a variety of formats.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. We know about Sandcastle and NDoc, but we were thinking an app where we could "drop" all our XML that VS produce and then this app could read them all, "index" them all like a huge library of project's doc and be able to do search in it. Maybe it's something not yet available... Sandcastle is good, but we need something that will be able to index all XML in a sort of library...!
Thanks again !